# After updating D-Link DWR M960 A2 firmware admin login page not showing up

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I updated the software of the router D-Link DWR M960 A2 model, after that the router's admin page did not show up on the laptop or on the mobile phone. Tell me solutions if anyone know that situation

Comment: Try turning the router off, wait 15 seconds, power back up. Does it recover?  Modern routers (my own) have an onboard backup of working firmware.

Comment: Where did you get the software update?

Comment: If it reset as part of the update maybe the IP address changed.

Answer (score 0):

(This is firmware recovery guide)

First of all, you need a ethernet cable to connect the router to a computer and the appropriate firmware file.
You can download the appropriate file from the following link (**Base on YOUR DEVICE VERSION**):

https://dlinkmea.com/index.php/product/details?det=azZBaklEMHdPVjFrK25YZzZWeXVpdz09#menu3

Then power OFF the device and Press the Reset button on router for 15 seconds.
Hold the RESET button then power ON the device and keep pressing the RESET button for about 15 seconds.

Now the recovery mode is activated on the router. But because the dhcp function does not work on the router, you need to set the IP manually.

To do so go to (on window 10):

> Settings -> Network & internet -> Ethernet -> Change adapter options

Select the right Ethernet adapter (if there are several).

Right click on it then:

> Properties -> select "Internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click on "Properties" -> "Use the following IP address"

Then enter as follows: (exclusively for DWR-M960)

- IP address: 192.168.1.2
- Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway: 192.168.1.6

then press OK.

[set the system IP manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juvcT.png)

In the browser put 192.168.1.6 and the recovery page  will appear. Just upload the firmware and wait.

If it doesn't work, ask DLink support for the appropriate firmware.

For more information: http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=65760.0

Thanks to: youtube.com/@smart-brain